# Code Style: Doctrine2 queries from entity repository?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, coding-style, entity, knppaginator

As I understand the best code style is to put the complex SQL/DQL queries to the entity repositories.

For example there is an entity named "News". It has an own entity repository named "NewsRepository".

In the controller there is this code:

```
/**
 * @Route("/news", name="news")
 */
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $paginator = $this->get('knp_paginator');

    $news = $paginator->paginate(
        $em->createQuery('SELECT n FROM AppBundle:News n'),
        $request->query->getInt('page', 1),
        10
    );

    return $this->render('app/news/list.html.twig', array(
        'news' => $news,
    ));
}
```

Now I like to add further features (filtering, order by, ..). That because I think the query should be moved to any service or the entity repository. But how and what is the best coding style?

(And does anybody have nice generic ideas how to easily add filtering, order by ... ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure,

Every request should be in the repository if you want use it again. Not only complexiest.

I'll try to answer your first question and after give you a tip that could help you with your "generic filtering"

If you want to put your request in the repo just make in your NewsRepository :

```
public function findAllOrderedByDate() {
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('n');
    $qb->orderBy('creationDate');

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

And in your controller :

```
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    $newsRepo = $this->get('doctrine')->getRepository('AppBundle:News');
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $paginator = $this->get('knp_paginator');

    $news = $newsRepo->findAllOrderedByDate();
    $pagination = $paginator->paginate(
        $news,
        $request->query->getInt('page', 1),
        10
    );

    return $this->render('app/news/list.html.twig', array(
        'news' => $pagination,
    ));
}
```

For the filtering, you have a trick in your repor that consist by returning the qb and not directly results.

As well, you can make a function that add you orderBy with a given parameter (using `addOrderBy()` or `andWhere`) and which return the queryBuilder. After all of that you can process.

EDIT :

---

The solution i read on this thread :

```
public function findAllOrderedByDate(callable $func = null) {
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('n');
    $qb->orderBy('creationDate');

    if (is_callable($func)) {
        return $func($qb);
    }
    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

and in your controller :

```
$func = function (QueryBuilder $qb) use ($paginator, $request) {
    return $paginator->paginate($qb, $request->query->getInt('page', 1), 10);
};
$pagination = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:News')->findAllOrderedByDate($func);
```

Comment: A little addition: if it would be very much records in getResult()/getArrayResult() - it is better to return queryBuilder object - paginator would query db for needed amount of records.

Comment: That is a very good question. For me, a repository has to return results. But I read a solution very interesting on this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22804158/how-to-use-knppaginatorbundle-to-paginate-results-using-doctrine-repository). that solution allow you to use paginator or not. I'll update my answer

Comment: I said it, just because I had experience with it)) - when there were too many results (don't remember how much, but more than 5k, and quantity grown up every minute - mPOS service). In this case (when working with paginator) - the best solution is to pass queryBuilder object - cause paginator would run result query with needed limits and offsets.

Comment: Yes, it's not worth to retrieve all entries for performances. I updated my answer. Just tell me if it's good for you.

Comment: Even first answer was alright!) I just mentioned one thing, that can potentially cause problems).

Answer (score 0):

Model part must be in model part. Move queries to repo's. 
And what do you mean, saying this: "nice generic ideas how to easily add filtering, order by"?
[OrderBy](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html#high-level-api-methods)
[Where](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html#high-level-api-methods) - same link